# How can I log [D]COM calls into a module?

Tags: com, automated-tests, dcom

Is there a way to monitor and record COM calls, with parameters, made into a specific EXE/DLL module, without explicitly adding logging functionality to the module itself? I'm thinking along the lines of how you can track windows messages in Spy++, but for COM.

The motivation is to record calls for diagnostic and automated testing purposes - e.g. click a button on a window on a client PC, monitor the COM calls sent to a server module, and later 'replay' those calls without needing the client PC.

If tools exist which do this, that is great. If not, is it something one could write and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

Caller of COM method simply calls a function with agreed convention. parameters etc. and there is no middle layer between the caller and the callee, except when proxy/stub pairs are marshaling the call. Even in the latter case, there is ho standard way to hook the call for logging purposes, which you can do without specific preparations of sorts. All in all, you need to take care of tracking calls and diagnostic yourself. In can direct logging in prolog of every method of interest, or you can wrap your object/interface into customized middle layer which tracks a call and passes it further to intended callee (such as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153096/Intercepting-Calls-to-COM-Interfaces), for example).

Comment: Ah, COM compiles right down to bare calls so there's nothing _to_ intercept like with messages. Thanks for that link. Am I right thinking a proxy can be provided in a totally separate module, without modifying the original - it is oblivious to the proxy? I suppose what I'd really be after is being able to autogenerate logging proxies from my IDL for the COM interfaces I'm interested in - does that sound feasible?

Comment: If you build a universal logging proxy, you still have to throw it in somewhere in real code, e.g. a method would return a proxy instead of bare interface pointer. I mean even though a proxy that covers lots of stuff can be done, the module to be tracked still has to have some code to integrate this proxy. You should look at it like this: my code works through pointers and methods follow some convention narrowing the diversity of possible calls to certain extent. How can I universally log the calls. Apparently the task is not as easy as just enabling something.

Comment: Forgive me labouring the point, but are you saying the hook to calls like CoCreateInstance have to be in the same module as the COM classes involved? Or can I create a brand new application which has a global hook, and creates proxies for specific IIDs?

Comment: `CoCreateInstance` is not the only API which gets you COM interfaces. Any COM method can return you an interface, directly or inside a VARIANT or structure etc. Basically you can hook something and you will get a fraction of calls to trace. If these are your specific calls of interest, you might want to give it a go, but without isolation of specific scope I would say that you're best direction is traditional logging/tracing right there in code.